# Read json file lead to - Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering

Tags: python, json, pandas

I need to extract data from website that allow API but I am getting error.
How can I overcome it?
Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('https://api.cbs.gov.il/index/data/price?id=120010&format=json&download=false')
df.to_excel('Data.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please add the code you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

To get data from url, you need to use **requests**,

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url='https://api.cbs.gov.il/index/data/price?id=120010&format=json&download=false'
s =requests.get(url).json()

data = pd.json_normalize(s)
data.to_csv('output_data.csv')
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks! but I get all the data that were extracted in one column and with tags. how can I organized in table form in the csv file?